# WhatPulse: Wrong token, did you use this profile on another computer?

Tags: windows-7, whatpulse

I got this error even though each of my computers use a different computer name:

[image]

Is there any way to solve the issue without losing the unpulsed stats?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with WhatPulse 3.4.1 (currently the latest version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to solve the issue without losing the unpulsed stats.